# How to animate the border of clicked link with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am new in to jQuery. I have been trying to figure out the animate function, and yet it still isn't working.

What I am trying to do is really simple. There is this link. If I click on it, I am supposed to see a border around it. But it isn't working. Here is my code

```
<a href="#">Click me</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(){
        $(this).animate({
            border-width: '2px'
            }, 1000, function(){
                alert('It has worked');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Try animating the individual border properties (e.g. borderWidth, borderColor, etc.)

Comment: jQuery doesn't understand the string `'2px solid red'`, you'll have to animate the `border-width` property, and for colors you need a color animation plugin.

Comment: I am sorry, but my code still isn't working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Animate only animate numerical property. You can't animate the border color and style.

Taken from jQuery website :

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.

[jQuery animate API page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

What I suggest you to do is to animate only the `border-width` and set other properties in the CSS files.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(){
        $(this).animate({
            'border-width': '2px'
            }, 1000, function(){
                alert('It has worked');
        });
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
a{
    border : 0 solid red;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/YQXr8/

Comment: What do you mean? if you set the border-width to 0, then no border will be shown.

Comment: No @eddard.stark, animate **only** works with numeric values (dimensional units), anything else will not work.

Comment: no, i mean if i want to set the visibility to hidden in the animate function, will it work?

Comment: Although, if you want to play with the visibility of an element, try with the `opacity` (because it expects a numeric value). Or better try to use `.fadeIn` / `.fadeOut`.

Comment: No but you can use `fadeTo(duration, 0)` and the element will be invisible but still take place on the DOM.